# Consumir web service HTTPS

Tags: java, web-service

Estou tentando consumir o webservice de CEP

> https://viacep.com.br/ws/88701001/json/

Estou utilizando Java Web - JSF com WildfFly10

Para isso estou utilizando o seguinte codigo.

```
String URL_WEBSERVICECEP = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/[CEP]/json/";
String urlCep = URL_WEBSERVICECEP.replace("[CEP]", "88701650");
System.out.println("------ url : "+urlCep);
URL url = new URL(urlCep);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream conS = con.getInputStream();
```

Porem esta dando o seguinte erro.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   br.com.transportesalvorada.security.controll.Usuario_MB.main(Usuario_MB.java:141)
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
>     ... 13 more Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
>     ... 19 more

Pelo que entendi não tem o certificado digital, realmente não possuo certificado.

O interessante é que se testo direto no browser funciona.

Comment: Eu consumo essa webservice no meu sistema e este também não tem certificado digital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver isso é criar uma fábrica de certificados para gerar um que te permita fazer chamadas a um serviço https. Esse é um exemplo da factory que eu criei pra certificados:

```
public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
private SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public CustomSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);
    TrustManager tm = gerarTrustManager();
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);

}

private X509TrustManager gerarTrustManager() {
    return new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

}
```

Aqui vai a leitura do certificado no cliente http:

```
protected void carregarContextoSSL(HttpClient httpClient) throws Exception {
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
    sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme(HTTPS, sf, 443));
}
```

Depois do método carregarContextoSSL é só chamar o httpClient.execute e não vai dar mais a exceção.

Comment: O código em si não se adequou ao meu problema. Mas sua sugestão me fez procurar por exemplo de factury. Muito Obrigado.  Para efeito de registrar quem enfrente o mesmo problema segue link. https://dzone.com/articles/how-setup-custom

Comment: Ótimo! A ideia é a mesma, só muda o client que você usa pra realizar as chamadas ao serviço.

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Se você testar direto no browser funcionará porque ele gerencia o download do certificado e sua aplicação não.

Os certificados ficam localizados em:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts
```

Para fazer funcionar, você deve ter o certificado. Como não é auto-assinado, pode fazer uma cópia da seguinte forma:

Faça o download do certificado pelo browser e com o auxílio da ferramenta keytool você pode adicionar o certificado em sua JVM onde roda o servidor.

keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias  -file    -keystore  -storepass

Depois de importar o certificado, colocá-lo em cacerts verifique se funciona.

Comment: Assim o fiz , Mas o erro Continua.  Veja a listagem 

C:\temp\certificado>keytool -list
Informe a senha da área de armazenamento de chaves:

Tipo de área de armazenamento de chaves: JKS
Fornecedor da área de armazenamento de chaves: SUN

Sua área de armazenamento de chaves contém 1 entrada

alvorada, 23/06/2016, trustedCertEntry,
Fingerprint (SHA1) do certificado: E0:02:6F:9B:4B:55:7B:2F:42:1E:6A:09:35:5B:99:05:12:34:86:57

C:\temp\certificado>

Answer (score 1):

Eu consumo essa webservice em meu sistema e também não tenho certificado digital.

O código que utilizo é o seguinte:

```
public static Address consultaCep(String cep) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Address e = new Address();
        String url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";

        //Ler Json a partir da URL
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int cp;
            while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) cp);
            }
            String jsonText = sb.toString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject json = gson.fromJson(jsonText, JsonObject.class);

            //vamos montar o endereço
            try{
                String erro = json.get("erro").getAsString();
                e.setZipCode(cep);
            } catch(Exception ex){
                //tem que entrar aqui, se não entrar é por que deu erro.
                e.setDistrict(json.get("bairro").getAsString());
                e.setZipCode(cep);
                e.setCity(json.get("localidade").getAsString());
                e.setState(json.get("uf").getAsString());
                e.setStreet(json.get("logradouro").getAsString());
            }
            return e;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Andrew.  Sem o certificado já ajuda. Contudo continuo sem saber como fazer funcionar com HTTPS.
De qualquer forma muito obrigado.